# Google Search Api Couldn't get Result More Than 4?

Tags: java, jsp

Here is my code that Search Result From Google.somewhere is written that i have to set 'start' to '0' but as i'm a very Newbee in java i really don't khow what should i do.so any help will appreciate.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@page import="com.demo.GoogleSearch"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@include file="SearchGoogle.jsp" %>
<%
String word=request.getParameter("searchWord");
List<String>urls=GoogleSearch.searchWord(word);

%>

<table>
<%
int b = urls.size();
for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
//if (i < b)
%>
<tr><td><%=urls.get(i) %></td></tr>
<%} %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is the page for Sesrch:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="SearchResults.jsp">
<table>
<tr><td>
Enter Search Word:</td><td>
<input type="text" name="searchWord"/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="search">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 4 search results is Google's limit on results when calling it through their API, unless you want to pay for the searches. In uni I had to make a project which needed to get results from a search engine, we used GigaBlast since it has a nice API and a much larger limit of results returned per search (50 if I recall right).

Comment: i don't think so cause it was written that we can increase the number of searches but i couldn't figured that out how that works.